Kuratowski 14 Set Theorem - non-algebraic proof
I am trying to understand the proof of the Kuratowski 14 Set Theorem. Here is my attempt at a proof.
For a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ and a set $A \subset X$, define $Int(A) = \{x \in A: \exists U \in \mathcal{T}, x \in U\subset A\}$. Then given an arbitrary set $A$, we can partition $X$ into $A_1 = Int(A)$, $A_2 = Int(A^C)$, and $A_3 = X-(A_1\cup A_2)$.
We state property 1: For a set $A$, every point $a \in A_3$ (as defined above) is a limit point of both $A$ and $A^C$ and also not an interior point of $\overline{A^C}$
Let $kA$ the closure of $A$ and $cA$ the complement of $A$. Then for a closed set $A$ satisfying property 1, we can form at most 4 distinct sets. These sets will be:
$$
A = A_1 \cup A_3
$$
$$
cA = A_2
$$
$$
kcA = A_2 \cup A_3
$$
$$
ckcA = A_1
$$
$$
kckcA = A_1 \cup A_3 = A
$$
We then claim that given an arbitrary set $A$, the operations of closure, complementation, and closure applied in that order produce a set having property 1. That is, for any $A$, the set $kckA$ is a set satisfying property 1, and therefore we can form at most 4 distinct sets from it. It then follows that we can form no more than 14 distinct sets from $A$ in total by repeated application of $k$ and $c$ operations.
To show that we can form at least 14 distinct sets I came up with the following set from which 14 distinct sets can be obtained by the repeated application of closure and complementation (in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$). This set is:
$$
A = (\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]) \cup \{a_n\} \cup [2,3)\cup(3,4]
$$
where $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in $(1,2)$ with a limit point also in $(1,2)$.
My specific questions are:
How can we show that given any closed set satisfying property 1, we can generate no more than 4 distinct sets through applying complementation and closure operations?
How can we show that given an arbitrary set $A$, that $kckA$ is a set satisfying property 1?

What do you mean when you say that one set "leads to" 14 sets? If you [edit] the question to tell us what particular step or set you are unsure about we may be able to help.

Could this be a duplicate of this oldie or some other on this list?

Thanks for the link; this question is useful and I will work through it. However the proof idea seems quite different, I am hoping to know if my idea will work.

It's true that $kckA$ yields no more than four distinct sets (including itself), where $kA$ and $cA$ are the closure and complement of $A$, respectively.  And yes, this is the key to getting $14$ as an upper bound.  Thus, if showing that $kckA:=k(c(kA))$ satisfying property 1 leads to $kckckckA$ equaling a set that's already in the list, then yes, property 1 has a meaningful role to play in the proof; i.e., the approach is viable.  But if it doesn't lead to such a set equation, then it's not viable.

Thanks! If kckA yields at most 4 distinct sets (including itself) then it seems like the result is proven. We take A, we get kA, ckA, kckA (+3 more), and we get cA, kcA, ckcA, kckcA (+3 more).  However, what I am hoping to ask about is if satisfying property 1 is sufficient for a set to generate no more than 4 distinct sets? And if so, can we confirm that given A, kckA is a set satisfying property 1?

The proof that closed $A$ satisfying property 1 yield only four sets is right there in your question (when taken along with the fact since $A$ is closed, $kA = A$; and for any set $B, kkB = kB, ccB = B$; so nothing is gained from either starting with $k$ or by  repeating either operator).

It might help to recast the definitions of $A_1, A_2, A_3$ in terms of $k$ instead of $Int$. For an arbitrary $A$, $$\begin{align}A_1 &= ckcA\A_2 &= ckA\A_3&=c(A_1 \cup A_2)=kcA \cap kA\end{align}$$
